# Selected variable highlighting and word separators in Sublime Text

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I removed the dollar sign from the list of word separators to be able to select PHP variables with double-clicks. Problem is when i select a variable: what i would expect is all other occurrences of the variable to be highlighted but it doesn't happen. Any idea?

Comment: Does it work in Sublime Text 2?  The reason I ask is to see if it is a problem with the pre-release/beta software (off topic on SU) or is a Sublime Text * issue (on topic on SU).

Comment: I just tried it on SB2 and it doesn't work. Should i remove the version from this answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working just fine for me in ST2 on XP. What may have happened is your `"match_selection"` setting might have gotten set to `false`. Make sure

```
"match_selection": true
```

is in your preferences file (`Preferences -> Settings - User`) and you should see the expected behavior.

---

***UPDATE***
After checking some other ST3 builds on a different machine, I was able to replicate the issue, however it doesn't seem to depend on whether `$` is included in the `"word_separators"` preference. Using the following test code:

```
<?php

function myFunc($var_1, $var_2) {
    return $var_1 + $var_2;
}
```

I selected `var_1` in one line, and the corresponding `var_1` was highlighted with a box around it, like usual. Same with `var_2`. Next, I selected `$var_1`, but the other occurrence was not highlighted. This behavior was the same regardless of whether `$` is defined as a word separator or not. Interestingly, even though the other `$var_1` wasn't highlighted, it was still able to be selected with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, so the bug is only with the highlighting code, not the search and select code.

https://github.com/SublimeText/Issues/issues is the unofficial repository for Sublime Text issues, mainly those having to do with ST3. I'd suggest you head over there, search around to see if anyone else has noticed this, and if not to open a new issue with as much detail as possible.

Comment: what versions/build numbers are you using? And what platform are you on?

Comment: I'm using ST3 build 3047 on Windows 7 Ultimate x64 (ST3 is portable edition)

Comment: If you're a registered user, try [Build 3053](http://www.sublimetext.com/3dev). Maybe something got broken somewhere...

Comment: I just logged into another machine running Build 3048 and I see the same thing - if I select just the text part of the variable, I see the corresponding part highlight elsewhere. However, if I include the `$`, no highlighting. I'd suggest heading over to the [unofficial ST3 issues tracker](https://github.com/SublimeText/Issues/issues) on GitHub, search around, then open an issue if no one has reported it yet.

Comment: Unfortunately, i'm not (yet) a registered user. I'll try reporting it as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround: sublime text package https://github.com/SublimeText/WordHighlight.
Referenced here: https://github.com/SublimeText/Issues/issues/212.

Comment: Please write out the answer from your reference on this site. If the link goes dead then so does this answer. Thanks for your contribution!